# How to retain focus for my nav button when I cancel my form submission in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a navigation bar with buttons where every button redirects you to another page. So on my first page from navigation bar I have a form submission. When I introduce data on the fields and accidentally want to navigate to another page from navigation bar I receive I confirmation window like this : 
Discard changes

Unsaved data will be lost, do you want to proceed? Yes / No. Even though I didn't selected No my navigation bar button which was clicked accidentally remains focused. How can I prevent this to happen?